How can I set a separate retention policy for a specific build in Azure Devops
What I want to do is to set the retention policy, probably through the REST interface, on a build. I want to do this through an API or other software as it will be looking at tasks and automatically setting the builds retention policy based on a field.
I don't want to set it for the project, just on a specific build.

The Azure DevOps - Leases API in the answer can retain a run forever. Which is the same as manually set a pipeline run to be retained using the More actions menu on the Pipeline run details page.

As per Set retention policies for builds, releases, and tests:
Azure DevOps no longer supports per-pipeline retention rules. The only way to configure retention policies for YAML and classic pipelines is through the project settings. You can no longer configure per-pipeline retention policies.
The alternative would be to use the Azure DevOps - Leases API to manage the lifetime of pipeline runs beyond the configured retention periods, which is the same as manually set retention lease on pipeline runs
